# Adding Admin user in ASPDotNetStoreFront Manually

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I want to create a user with Admin privilleges in ASPDotNetStoreFront 9.3 Manually, without using the interface, I don't have good knowlege of ASPDSF database, I explored DB but could not found Users and roles tables and their mapping tables etc. Any one plz guide me about required steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no user table, but a customer table.  Everything you need is in that table.  They use the IsAdmin field to denote the user role.  Now that being said, there is a way to import customer information (called WSI) and this is the correct way to do it.  Here is the link - http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/c-144-wsi.aspx.  Essentially, you use XML to import the customer information.  Here is another link to their test program - http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-1434-test-application.aspx and hopefully it will help in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @wade so it means if i add some customer manually in customer table and mark it as admin then it will work properly or have to do update any mapping table as well? and what about if i want to make user super admin

Comment: You only need to mark the customer as admin or superadmin, no other setup needed.